# Saving selenium web elements into a file

Tags: python, selenium, pickle

I am trying to save selenium web elements into a separate file for later use in my program to find that element easily on the same website. I tried with pickle and continuously I am getting the following error.

```
 AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'
```

Tried setting the local variable into `global`, but still no luck.

Here is an example code to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://website.com/')

anchors = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

for anchor in anchors:
    with open('anchors_pickle', 'wb') as pick_file:
        pickle.dump(anchor, pick_file)  # Error
```

Since with JSON also this is not possible, I guess pickle is the best solution for this. Is there any method to overcome this error?

Comment: DOM node representation that you try to save to file bind with current webdriver session, and it can't be stored separatly (easily). You can try to get related HTML representation of node and save it as regular text: `anchor.get_attribute('outerHTML')`.

Comment: @Stanislav Ivanov 
What is the difference between this and anchor.get_attribute('innerHTML')? My auto-pilot kept suggesting the latter

Comment: @Egret It works too. Look for example: `<a><b></b></a>`: calling `get_attribute('innerHTML')` will returns `<b></b>`, but `get_attribute('outerHTML')` will returns `<a><b></b></a>`.